# Ways to find duplicates & partial matches in a column

Tags: google-sheets, aggregate, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, partial-matches

Without using script, what options do I have to detect duplicates / partial matches?

**Background:**

- I have a large list of names in a column A (using the UNIQUE function).
- In the column there are duplicate names which are misspelled.

```
|        A     |  B  |
| John Doe     |     |
| Joen Doe     |     |
| Jane Smith   |     |
| Jane Smithh  |     |
```

**Attempted Solution**

- With Excel I can use Aggregate/Row/Search, but this does not work with Google Sheets.

**Ideas (that might work)**

1. Formula that will detect if name in A2, contains 75% or more of the same letters found in A3:A.

> Options:
>
> - If 75% or more, in B2 write TRUE
> - If 75% or more, Conditional formatting - highlight cell

2. Formula to detect if the first 3 letters in A2, match the first 3 letters in A3:A

> Options:
>
> - If first 3 letters match, in B2 write TRUE
> - If first 3 letters match, Conditional formatting - highlight cell
> - Wont be as accurate of there is a typo within the first 3 letters.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: James, I would recommend that you share a sample spreadsheet with more data to work with than four short names. Writing a complex formula around such a small data set is all but guaranteed to fail against the actual data and is therefore an inefficient use of time. Just makes sure to set such a link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." The best scenario would be if you could include your actual list of raw names with no other personal data.

Comment: Misspelling is a too complex problem to be solved within a few lines of code. First - you may make mistake in letters order. Second - you can mistake letters, third - you can add letters or skip letters. Many names are correct but very similar - like Jean, Joan, John, Jon and Johann. Some real names look like errors because it was an error made a few generations ago...

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution? I have a similar situation and need a solution myself.